# American Fuzzy Lop run test program as unprivileged user or in chroot

Tags: shell-script, permissions, chroot

I'm attempting to test `tcsh` on OS X with American Fuzzy Lop as an exercise, but don't want to accidentally clobber any useful files on my system.

Knowing essentially nothing about fuzz testing, I did the following:

I installed the fuzzer through brew.

```
$ brew install afl-fuzz
```

as a side node, the `tcsh` configure script seems to ignore the `--disable-shared` flag.

```
$ ./configure CC=afl-clang --disable-shared --prefix="$HOME"/opt/fuzzy-local ; make
```

Then gave it a stupid example test script: `samples/sample.csh`

```
echo '45'
```

Then I ran afl-fuzz for a while in the most naive way possible.

```
$ afl-fuzz -i samples -o afl_findings ./bin/tcsh -f @@
```

I soon discovered that the randomly generated shell scripts had created some garbage files.

```
$ ls
?d%FF%FFd%A7    ?               5?              bin             share
?45?            45              afl_findings    samples
```

What would be the correct way to limit the things that the randomly generated shell scripts can do and stop them from potentially deleting or modifying files I care about.

I went on to try

```
$ chown nobody:nogroup afl-findings
$ sudo -u nobody afl-fuzz -i samples -o all_findings ./bin/tcsh -f @@
```

but I'm not sure that does a good enough job of constraining what randomly generated shell scripts can do.